# Document object modification in function using Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a function such as:

```py
def my_function(obj, X):
    """My function.

    :param obj: An instance of object.
    :type obj: object

    :param A: An array
    :type A: :class:`numpy.ndarray`

    """

    obj.fs['X'] = X.shape

    obj.d['v'] = obj.fs['X'][0]
    obj.d['t'] = obj.fs['X'][1]
    obj.d['m'] = obj.fs['X'][2]

    #: Comment here
    hv = obj.fs['Uh'] = (obj.d['h'], obj.d['v'])
    hh = obj.fs['Vh'] = (obj.d['h'], obj.d['h'])
    h1 = obj.fs['bh'] = (obj.d['h'], 1)

    # Etc...

    return None
```

I document this function with Sphinx using:

```
.. autofunction:: path.my_function
```

I would like to have a way documenting blocks of code. I know there is `#: Comment` but is does not seem to work with `.. autofunction::`.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/48674189/407651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a misconception because what is documented in an API are signatures of constructs (e.g. classes, methods, functions, etc...) not the internal sections of code. As mentioned [in @mzjn's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674189) that is what PEP 257 defines as the use of docstrings.

The one exception to this is documenting attributes (which is what the `#:` syntax is used for in Sphinx), but in general you only expose class level and module level user defined attributes (never function scoped attributes).

In your case from the description the correct option is to split internal regions within a construct by using [a code region](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8265583). (But notice this style of internal documenting should only concern developers who will look beyond the API and into the source code. Whatever functionality is implemented by the function should be documented textually in the docstring in terms of parameters and returns thus hiding any internals.)

```py
def my_function(obj, X):
    """My function.

    :param obj: An instance of object.
    :type obj: object

    :param A: An array
    :type A: :class:`numpy.ndarray`

    """

    # region Adding attributes to argument object.
    obj.fs['X'] = X.shape

    obj.d['v'] = obj.fs['X'][0]
    obj.d['t'] = obj.fs['X'][1]
    obj.d['m'] = obj.fs['X'][2]
    # endregion
    
    # region USUALLY A ONE-LINER HERE
    # If the above isn't enough expand it by writing more comment lines.
    hv = obj.fs['Uh'] = (obj.d['h'], obj.d['v'])  # Inline comment.
    hh = obj.fs['Vh'] = (obj.d['h'], obj.d['h'])
    h1 = obj.fs['bh'] = (obj.d['h'], 1)
    # endregion

    # Etc...

    return None
```

However, the above is not without a few possible exceptions in rarer use cases. The problem is the autodoc extension follows the prevalent rules explained above, thus for the `.. autofunction::` and `..automethod::` directives the documentation explicitly states:

> [`.. autofunction::`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autofunction)
>
> These work exactly like autoclass etc., **but do not offer the options used for automatic member documentation.**

One example that defies the previous logic and seems similar to your use case, would be documenting a factory method that adds extra attributes to the created instance. You would say this textually in the docstring or `.rst` file by [cross-referencing](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-syntax) the extra attributes. However this would still violate the [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and usual logic of encapsulation, because users expect attributes of a class/object to be those the object is initially declared with.

There is, however, a technical solution if you really want this OO design. Instead of simply using:

```
.. autofunction:: path.my_function
```

Use the Python domain [`.. py:attribute::`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-py-attribute) to declare the variables in the `.rst` file. The drawback of this is that it doesn't extract the text you write with the `:#` syntax in the source code. However it does allow to implement the documentation exactly as you intended in the original question.

```
.. autofunction:: path.my_function

   .. py:attribute:: path.my_function.hv 
      
      Some text about the attribute.

   .. py:attribute:: path.my_function.hh 
      
      Some text about the attribute.

   .. py:attribute:: path.my_function.h1 
      
      Some text about the attribute.
```