# how to organize my code into multiple files to share a common global variable

Tags: python

**Pre**:
not about threading nor multiprocessing, there won't be any concurrency concerns. This is more of a question on how to organize python files in a project.

**intention:**
the shared var is a global dictionary `global_dict`
my whole code is to simply setup this dict and use it later, as simple as the pseudo code below:

```
global_dict = {}

########################### FIRST PORTION OF THE CODE ###########################

# [step 0] 
lengthy computations and file ios to compute the keyname and content to be added to global_dict
global_dict['keyname00'] = content00

# [step 1] 
distinct from other steps lengthy computations and file ios to compute the keyname and content to be added to global_dict
global_dict['keyname01'] = content01

....

# [step ##] 
distinct from other steps lengthy computations and file ios to compute the keyname and content to be added to global_dict
global_dict['keyname##'] = content##

########################### SECOND PORTION OF THE CODE ###########################
# now we have setup the dictionary, we can use it here
myclass = myclass(global_dict)
myclass.dostuff()
```

**what I would like to achieve:**
I can not fit all the code that sets up the `global_dict` (i.e. the `[step ##]` code) into one python file, too lengthy and too hard to navigate, I have to break it apart.

**what I have attempted so far:**
I have broken the single file into multiple files:

`file global_dict.py`

```
global_dict = {}
```

`file step00.py`

```
from global_dict import global_dict
lengthy computations and file ios to compute the keyname and content to be added to global_dict
global_dict['keyname00'] = content00
```

`file step01.py` ...  `file step##.py`

```
from global_dict import global_dict
lengthy computations and file ios to compute the keyname and content to be added to global_dict
global_dict['keyname##'] = content##
```

`mainline.py`

```
from global_dict import global_dict
for pyfile in current working dir:
    importlib.import_module(pyfile)
```

**The code above is working alright, however felt clumsy and unsettling, but couldn't think of a better way. Need help.**

**P.S.**
the contents of `global_dict` is not pickle-able.

Thank you for your helpful suggestions, but I believe I simplified my actual code too much. In my actual code, I do have an `inline()` or `main()` function in each `step##.py` to handle the modification of dictionary. So in my `main.py`, I call all my `step##.py`s thusly:

```
for fp in sorted( # fp: filepath of all the setup py files
        (path_setups).glob('*.py')
    ):
    if fp.stem != '__init__':
        setup = importlib.import_module('sigs.inline_setups.' + fp.stem)
        logging.info(setup)
        setup.inline() # <========= inline() is the func that modifies `global_dict`
```

Comment: The fact that you repeat `from global_dict import global_dict` in each file is the problem?

Comment: suprisingly no, without it, it won't work. wierd, I know. thats why it is so... "unsettling". Also python itself has safeguard, so that something imported already won't be imported again. I have to import the `global_dict` in all the "steps.py"s so that those py files can resolve the name. The main.py 's import is probably redundant.

Comment: You could transform all your code inside each file in a function that would take `global_dict` as input. Then in your `mainline.py` , you would import `global_dict` only once and pass it to each function in each file.

Comment: if you use Pycharm you can divide your file in multiple collapsable regions. Maybe then you don;t need to split into several files   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265583/dividing-python-module-into-multiple-regions

Comment: Just for clarification: Each of your separate stepXX.py files, when imported, actually executes some code and writes the result to the shared dictionary?

Comment: I think the basic problem may be that scripts that modify global objects always seem a little hazy and "magical". You could try writing a function in each module that does its main work. Then import each of those functions into mainline.py and define `globaldict` there too. Then call each function with `globaldict` as an argument. This way you can see the flow of the program clearly and not rely on basically side effects from the import statements. (Looks like @kelyen beat me to this.)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yes, unsettling, but yes.

Comment: Okay, in that case, I'd say the cleanest way is to not use a global at all. Instead, the functions just return a value, which you can integrate into a local variable, if you want to. Remember, you can return arbitrary complex objects from a function and even return multiple objects. Unless there's more to this story, that should be a usable approach.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thank you, that's what the accepted answer suggests as well. Actually, most of sane person would end up with that approach as well. I fell into a trap of cleaning up a bigger mess into my current mess, the way of thinking was stuck in the "mess". Simplifying the mess into a stackoverflow question helps me to see things clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this the other way around, modify your code so that you can follow this pattern:

```py
import step00
import step01
import step02

global_dict = {}

step00.main()
step01.main()
step02.main()
```

That will do what you want.  However, it is easy to 'improve' your code to not require a global dictionary this way as well:

```py
import step00
import step01
import step02

my_dict = {}

step00.main(my_dict)
step01.main(my_dict)
step02.main(my_dict)
```

Comment: uhh man... it does answer the question I asked, thank you. but it does not solve the actual code I have. I had to simplify my actual code into the question.

my biggest problem is that, those "step.py" files are not named uniformly... and they are regularly subtracted and added to the project. as matter of fact, those "step.py"s are kinda auto generated according some other image/pickle filenames. So `for every py file in dir: import py file` needs to stay

Comment: You can still import like that and use this solution

Comment: you know what, thank you. I think yours have a major improvement. While I do use `main()` in my `steps##.py`s, my `main()`s do not take the `global_dict` as an argument, but it uses the `global global_dict` syntax within the `main()` and relies on the `from global_dict import global_dict` in each `steps##.py` to resolve the name.

Comment: In the first solution, the `main()` functions will not have access to `global_dict`.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp true, but it was more of illustrative pseudo code. His second solution is the real solution.